# Joining Columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

**Workcenter:**

```
WC #  Activity1  activity2  activity3  activity4  
1     Labor      Run       Setup        Helper  
2      Setup      Helper    Labor           
3      Helper     Run
```

**Actvity:**

```
WC #    Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
1        1     2    3        4  
2        12    13   14  
3        21    22
```

My final outcome would be:

```
Wc#     Labortime Runtime Setuptime helpertime  
1         1         2      3           4  
2        14        13     12  
3        0         22      0           21
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please tag database you are using, also did you looked around in stack for similar questions answered. SO users appreciate if you can attempt writing a query and we will help improve it

Comment: Also indicate if you know the exact five columns in the result set or if they need to be determined from the first table.

Comment: Can you clarify your logic? Work Center 2 seems to have times specified for Setup, Helper, and Labor; however, your expected results show values under Labor, Run, and Setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found, I'm sure not the best one was to `UNPIVOT` your two tables (in 2 `CTEs`) and then join the results, based on your `[WC #]` and column numbers (name)(as you can see I have added an number at the beginning of the column names, in the `UNPIVOT` query to make sure I get the correct time for each activity).
Saved everything in an temporary table and used `PIVOT` for final result.

```
declare @workcenter as table (
    wc int
    ,activity1 varchar(10)
    ,activity2 varchar(10)
    ,activity3 varchar(10)
    ,activity4 varchar(10)
);

insert into @workcenter values
(1, 'Labour', 'Run', 'Setup', 'Helper')
,(2, 'Setup', 'Helper', 'Labour', NULL)
,(3, 'Helper', 'Run', NULL, NULL)



declare @activity as table (
    wc int
    ,time1 int
    ,time2 int
    ,time3 int
    ,time4 int
);


insert into @activity values
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
,(2, 12, 13, 14, NULL)
,(3, 21, 22, NULL, NULL)



;with cte_wc as (
    select
        wc
        ,cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by wc) as varchar)+ name as name
        ,value
    from @workcenter
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for name in (activity1, activity2, activity3,activity4)
    ) unpiv
)
, cte_a as (
    select
        wc
        ,cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by wc) as varchar)+ name as name
        ,value
    from @activity
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for name in (time1, time2, time3,time4)
    ) unpiv
)

select distinct
    cte_wc.wc
    ,cte_wc.value as activity
    ,cte_a.value as time
into #tbl
from cte_wc
inner join cte_a
    on cte_wc.wc = cte_a.wc
    and LEFT(cte_wc.name, 1) = LEFT(cte_a.name, 1);



select *
from 
(
  select wc, activity, time
  from #tbl
) src
pivot
(
  max(time)
  for activity in ([Labour], [Run], [Setup], [Helper])
) piv;



drop table #tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You check this below script. Althoug there are some mimatch between the output and your expected output, I think there are some wrong expected output in your given data.

```
SELECT A.[WC #],
ISNULL(
CASE 
    WHEN  Activity1 = 'Labor' THEN Time1 
    WHEN  Activity2 = 'Labor' THEN Time2
    WHEN  Activity3 = 'Labor' THEN Time3
    WHEN  Activity4 = 'Labor' THEN Time4
    ELSE NULL
END,0) Labortime,
ISNULL(
CASE 
    WHEN  Activity1 = 'Run' THEN Time1 
    WHEN  Activity2 = 'Run' THEN Time2
    WHEN  Activity3 = 'Run' THEN Time3
    WHEN  Activity4 = 'Run' THEN Time4
    ELSE NULL
END,0) Runtime,
ISNULL(
CASE 
    WHEN  Activity1 = 'Setup' THEN Time1 
    WHEN  Activity2 = 'Setup' THEN Time2
    WHEN  Activity3 = 'Setup' THEN Time3
    WHEN  Activity4 = 'Setup' THEN Time4
    ELSE NULL
END,0) Setuptime,
ISNULL(
CASE 
    WHEN  Activity1 = 'Helper' THEN Time1 
    WHEN  Activity2 = 'Helper' THEN Time2
    WHEN  Activity3 = 'Helper' THEN Time3
    WHEN  Activity4 = 'Helper' THEN Time4
    ELSE NULL
END,0) helpertime
FROM Workcenter A
INNER JOIN Actvity B ON A.[WC #] = B.[WC #]
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I would strongly recommend that you change your database structure. As it stands now, your structure is not ideal: If a work-center needs a 5th activity, you'll have to make structural changes to your tables, which is not ideal. Also, as evidenced by the other 2 answers, your queries are going to be convoluted.

I think a far better design is to have one table that includes the following attributes:

- `work_center_id` (which may possibly be a foreign key to a table of work-centers)
- `activity_name` (or `activity_name_id`), which may be a foreign key to a table of possible activities
- `activity_time` (possibly `activity_time_seconds`, to clarify what it's measuring).

Your data presented in this table would look something like this:

```
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| work_center_id | activity_name | activity_time |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
|              1 | Labor         |             1 |
|              1 | Run           |             2 |
|              1 | Setup         |             3 |
|              1 | Helper        |             4 |
|              2 | Setup         |            12 |
|              2 | Helper        |            13 |
|              2 | Labor         |            14 |
|              3 | Helper        |            21 |
|              3 | Run           |            22 |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Then, to get the data you want, you can use a basic pivot query, e.g. using conditional aggregation as illustrated below:

```
SELECT
    work_center_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Labor'   THEN activity_time ELSE 0 END) AS Labortime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Run'     THEN activity_time ELSE 0 END) AS Runtime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Setup'   THEN activity_time ELSE 0 END) AS Setuptime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Helper'  THEN activity_time ELSE 0 END) AS Helpertime
FROM activity_times
GROUP BY work_center_id
```